# Third condition in ternery operator doesn't render when condition is met

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to figure out where I am going wrong with this ternery.

It isn't rendering the last element (blurredscreen) if `authStatus !== "authenticated"`.

```
  return (
      <>
        <div key={"key-" + id}>
          {isOpen && (
            <div>
              {authStatus === "authenticated" &&
                (header.x && header.x.t === "abc" ? (
                  <div
                    onClick={(e) => {
                      e.stopPropagation();
                    }}
                  >
                    <ComponentOne />
                  </div>
                ) : header.x && header.x.t === "def" ? (
                  <div
                    onClick={(e) => {
                      e.stopPropagation();
                    }}
                  >
                    <ComponentTwo />
                  </div>
                ) : ( //this is the part that doesn't display when condition is met
                  authStatus !== "authenticated" &&
                  !header.x && (
                    <div>
                      <img
                        src={blurredScreen}
                       />
                      <button
                        onClick={handleSignInClick}
                      >
                        <span style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>Login </span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  )
                ))}
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </>
    );
```

Comment: Your code is like this: `authStatus === "authenticated" && (.....<other code> authStatus != "authenticated" )`. It is inside the second `()` which will only execute when `authStatus === "authenticated"`. Use ternary like you are using with `header.x.t`

Comment: So a second ternery?

Comment: I would suggest avoiding over use of tenery when rendering with React, that code just looks terrible, and as you have found makes finding bugs X times harder..

Comment: To make your code much easier to understand, convert your code to simple `if else`. An advantage is that all code paths have to be met. You can do this by just assigning the JSX to a local var, and render this.

Comment: im not familiar with this method of assigning to variable and rendering this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overuse of tenery operator in JSX can lead to really confusing code and makes it hard to debug.  The posters question is a good example, there are only 3 conditional routes and the code looks very confusing, as you can imagine this only gets more complicated with 4,5+.. etc.

The good news, you can still use `if else` inside React, just assign your JSX to a local variable and render this.

Below is a simple example that flips between 3 states, and as you can see is much easier to reason with.

```js
const {useEffect, useState, Fragment} = React;


function Demo() {
  const [s, setS] = useState(0);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const t = setInterval(() => setS(c => c +1), 1000);
    return () => { clearInterval(t) }
  }, []);
  
  let render = null;
  let d = s % 3;
  
  if (d === 0) {
    render = <div>This is 0</div>
  } else if (d ===1) {
    render = <div>This is One</div>
  } else {
    render = <div>Everything else</div>
  }
  
  //Fragment used here, because SO Snippet
  //do not transpile <>....</>
  return <Fragment>{render}</Fragment>
}


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<Demo/>);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Also notice I set `let render = null;`, this is deliberate, `null` is a valid JSX type that renders nothing.  So if for some reason no code paths are met, React will render nothing instead of throwing an error.  Of course in the above example that's not going to happen, but it's good habit to get into. If your on React 18, you can now leave out the `null`. https://blog.saeloun.com/2022/04/14/react-18-allows-components-to-render-undfined.html

Comment: @deadant88  No problem, it can take a while to get the best out of React, but each day we learn something new, it seems to get easier.